# Import CSV into PostgreSQL, matching keys

Tags: postgresql

I have a CSV file that i want to import into my existing PostgreSQL database, that would add an additional column with data. The CSV contains the primary key ID to match the data with, and the balance attached to it. How would I go about importing this CSV to automatically match it with the existing primary key ID, without overwriting other data?

Comment: I highly suggest reviewing your question. Please include important things like the CSV, the table structure, the language/tool you are using and what you have tried so far.

Comment: In two steps. Load it in to a staging table, then insert from that table into the destination table, including a join to acquire the extra column.